# Appscript time based trigger running every every second instead of 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have the code written out as such

```
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
}
```

But when I check the execution log it shows that it's being triggered every second.
Because it's running so often it's causing issues and sending emails saying that it's failed when in reality it's doing what it is supposed to.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you have a trigger running every second.

Comment: First question is how are you using the function?  Is it a custom function that is placed in a cell?.  Please provide [mcve]

Comment: This is the execution log of the script. 

Deployment
Function
Type
Start Time
Duration
Status
Head Payscan Time-Driven Apr 10, 2022, 1:02:19 AM 0.563 s 
Completed
Head Payscan Time-Driven Apr 10, 2022, 1:02:10 AM 0.697 s 
Completed
Head Payscan Time-Driven Apr 10, 2022, 1:02:00 AM 0.598 s 
Completed
Head Payscan Time-Driven Apr 10, 2022, 1:01:55 AM 0.487 s 
Completed
Head Payscan Time-Driven Apr 10, 2022, 1:01:19 AM 0.498 s 
Completed
Head Payscan Time-Driven Apr 10, 2022, 1:01:10 AM 0.604 s 
Completed
Head Payscan Time-Driven Apr 10, 2022, 1:01:00 AM 0.433 s 
Completed

Comment: I don't know what a head payscan is but I guess I'd delete the trigger and create another.

Answer (score 1):

This had 4 triggers running every minute causing it to run multiple times in a minute, deleting them worked and now it seems to run every minute without causing any issues.